# Amazon web services Throttling

Tags: amazon-web-services

Currently I have two applications querying Amazon Web Services.

Application 'A' has been whitelisted, I can still query the old Product advertising API using AWS.

Appilication 'B' uses the MWS system.

It appears that application 'A' queries apply to Application 'B' throttle limit. Is this accurate?

If I am accessing to different API's will the throttling limit be shared between them??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was the Product Advertising api has its own throttle that doesnt reflect on the MWS throttling system.

The question is now moot as the Product advertising API is removed.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the below link:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/limits.html

It is not clear which AWS service your APIs are consuming. But in general e.g if you are using KMS integration, then there is a limit for number of concurrent connections for a region for your account. And it will throttle if you go beyond the published limits.